How to save ContainerData in Item?
How can I move the ContainerData, LazyItemHandler and ItemHandler from a BlockEntity to an Item?
My idea is, is that I wan't to have an USB-Stick with a storage bound to that specfic USB-Stick. The storage should be able to be opened with rightclicking a computer.
I made it work that I can open a ComputerMenu when holding a USB-Stick. But now it saves the ContainerData to the Block itself.
public class ComputerBlockEntity extends BlockEntity implements MenuProvider {
    private final ItemStackHandler itemHandler = new ItemStackHandler(9);

    private LazyOptional<IItemHandler> lazyItemHandler = LazyOptional.empty();

    protected final ContainerData data;

    public ComputerBlockEntity(BlockPos pPos, BlockState pBlockState) {
        super(ModBlockEntities.COMPUTER_BE.get(), pPos, pBlockState);
        this.data = new ContainerData() {
            @Override
            public int get(int i) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void set(int i, int i1) { }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull <T> LazyOptional<T> getCapability(@NotNull Capability<T> cap, @Nullable Direction side) {
       if (cap == ForgeCapabilities.ITEM_HANDLER) {
           return lazyItemHandler.cast();
       }

       return super.getCapability(cap, side);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        lazyItemHandler = LazyOptional.of(() -> itemHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateCaps() {
        super.invalidateCaps();
        lazyItemHandler.invalidate();
    }

    public void drops() {
        SimpleContainer inventory = new SimpleContainer(itemHandler.getSlots());
        for (int i = 0; i < itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            inventory.setItem(i, itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i));
        }

        Containers.dropContents(this.level, this.worldPosition, inventory);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getDisplayName() {
        return Component.translatable("container.informatikermod.computer");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AbstractContainerMenu createMenu(int i, Inventory inventory, Player player) {
        return new ComputerMenu(i, inventory, this, this.data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void saveAdditional(CompoundTag pTag) {
        pTag.put("inventory", itemHandler.serializeNBT());
        super.saveAdditional(pTag);
    }

    @Override
    public void load(CompoundTag pTag) {
        super.load(pTag);
        itemHandler.deserializeNBT(pTag.getCompound("inventory"));
    }
}

public class Computer extends BaseEntityBlock {
    public static final DirectionProperty FACING = BlockStateProperties.HORIZONTAL_FACING;

    public Computer(Properties pProperties) {
        super(pProperties);
    }

    /* FACING */
    @Override
    public BlockState getStateForPlacement(BlockPlaceContext pContext) {
        return this.defaultBlockState().setValue(FACING, pContext.getHorizontalDirection().getOpposite());
    }

    @Override
    public BlockState rotate(BlockState pState, Rotation pRotation) {
        return pState.setValue(FACING, pRotation.rotate(pState.getValue(FACING)));
    }

    @Override
    public BlockState mirror(BlockState pState, Mirror pMirror) {
        return pState.rotate(pMirror.getRotation(pState.getValue(FACING)));
    }

    @Override
    public InteractionResult use(BlockState pState, Level pLevel, BlockPos pPos, Player pPlayer, InteractionHand pHand, BlockHitResult pHit) {
        if (!pLevel.isClientSide()) {
            BlockEntity blockEntity = pLevel.getBlockEntity(pPos);
            if (blockEntity instanceof ComputerBlockEntity && pPlayer.getMainHandItem().getItem().equals(ModItems.USB_STICK.get())) {
                NetworkHooks.openScreen(((ServerPlayer) pPlayer), (ComputerBlockEntity) blockEntity, pPos);
            }
        }

        return InteractionResult.sidedSuccess(pLevel.isClientSide());
    }

    @Override
    protected void createBlockStateDefinition(StateDefinition.Builder<Block, BlockState> pBuilder) {
        pBuilder.add(FACING);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public BlockEntity newBlockEntity(BlockPos blockPos, BlockState blockState) {
        return new ComputerBlockEntity(blockPos, blockState);
    }
}

public class ComputerBlockEntity extends BlockEntity implements MenuProvider {
    private final ItemStackHandler itemHandler = new ItemStackHandler(9);

    private LazyOptional<IItemHandler> lazyItemHandler = LazyOptional.empty();

    protected final ContainerData data;

    public ComputerBlockEntity(BlockPos pPos, BlockState pBlockState) {
        super(ModBlockEntities.COMPUTER_BE.get(), pPos, pBlockState);
        this.data = new ContainerData() {
            @Override
            public int get(int i) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void set(int i, int i1) { }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull <T> LazyOptional<T> getCapability(@NotNull Capability<T> cap, @Nullable Direction side) {
       if (cap == ForgeCapabilities.ITEM_HANDLER) {
           return lazyItemHandler.cast();
       }

       return super.getCapability(cap, side);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        lazyItemHandler = LazyOptional.of(() -> itemHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateCaps() {
        super.invalidateCaps();
        lazyItemHandler.invalidate();
    }

    public void drops() {
        SimpleContainer inventory = new SimpleContainer(itemHandler.getSlots());
        for (int i = 0; i < itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            inventory.setItem(i, itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i));
        }

        Containers.dropContents(this.level, this.worldPosition, inventory);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getDisplayName() {
        return Component.translatable("container.informatikermod.computer");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AbstractContainerMenu createMenu(int i, Inventory inventory, Player player) {
        return new ComputerMenu(i, inventory, this, this.data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void saveAdditional(CompoundTag pTag) {
        pTag.put("inventory", itemHandler.serializeNBT());
        super.saveAdditional(pTag);
    }

    @Override
    public void load(CompoundTag pTag) {
        super.load(pTag);
        itemHandler.deserializeNBT(pTag.getCompound("inventory"));
    }
}

public class UsbStickItem extends Item {
    // Store the data in this item

    public UsbStickItem(Properties properties) {
        super(properties);
    }
}

public class ModBlockEntities {
    public static final DeferredRegister<BlockEntityType<?>> BLOCK_ENTITIES =
            DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.BLOCK_ENTITY_TYPES, InformatikerMod.MOD_ID);

    public static final RegistryObject<BlockEntityType<ComputerBlockEntity>> COMPUTER_BE =
            BLOCK_ENTITIES.register("computer_be", () ->
                    BlockEntityType.Builder.of(ComputerBlockEntity::new, ModBlocks.COMPUTER.get()).build(null));

    public static void register(IEventBus eventBus) {
        BLOCK_ENTITIES.register(eventBus);
    }
}

I made it work that I can open a ComputerMenu when holding a USB-Stick. But now it saves the ContainerData to the Block itself instead of the UsbStickItem.
